# Date containing weekday/Month/Day/Year can't be correctly parsed by Lubridate

Tags: r, regex, lubridate, stringr

### The problem

I am downloaded a database from a website and the Daye column is in the following format:

```
x <- c("Fri, Mar 1, 2019", "Sat, Mar 2, 2019", "Sun, Mar 3, 2019", "Mon, Mar 4, 2019", "Tue, Mar 5, 2019", "Wed, Mar 6, 2019", "Thu, Mar 7, 2019", "Fri, Mar 8, 2019", "Sat, Mar 9, 2019", "Sun, Mar 10, 2019", "Mon, Mar 11, 2019", "Tue, Mar 12, 2019", "Wed, Mar 13, 2019", "Thu, Mar 14, 2019", "Fri, Mar 15, 2019", "Sat, Mar 16, 2019", "Sun, Mar 17, 2019", "Mon, Mar 18, 2019", "Tue, Mar 19, 2019", "Wed, Mar 20, 2019", "Thu, Mar 21, 2019", "Fri, Mar 22, 2019", "Sat, Mar 23, 2019", "Sun, Mar 24, 2019", "Mon, Mar 25, 2019",  "Tue, Mar 26, 2019", "Wed, Mar 27, 2019", "Thu, Mar 28, 2019", "Fri, Mar 29, 2019", "Sat, Mar 30, 2019", "Sun, Mar 31, 2019")
```

Which contains the dates from March 1st to the 31st. I am trying to transform it to a Date format, so I used y `,dy` function in lubridate:

```
library("lubridate")
mdy(x)
```

Which resulted in the following vector:

```
 [1] "2019-03-01" "2019-03-02" "2019-03-20" "2019-04-20" "2019-05-20" "2019-03-06"
 [7] "2019-03-07" "2019-03-08" "2019-03-09" "2019-10-20" "2019-11-20" "2019-12-20"
[13] "2019-03-13" "2019-03-14" "2019-03-15" "2019-03-16" "2019-03-17" "2019-03-18"
[19] "2019-03-19" "2019-03-20" "2019-03-21" "2019-03-22" "2019-03-23" "2019-03-24"
[25] "2019-03-25" "2019-03-26" "2019-03-27" "2019-03-28" "2019-03-29" "2019-03-30"
[31] "2019-03-31"
```

As you can see most of the dates are correct, but it does not work for the 4th, 5th, 10th, 11th and 12th day of the month, where it reads the day as if it was the month. I have been trying several solutions but none has worked so far

### Some possible solutions that have not worked

#### Using regex to remove weekday from the character vector:

I thought one way of solving this was removing the weekday part of the string, so I tried to remove everything before the comma, which I was able to do imperfectly:

```
library(stringr)
y <- str_extract(Dt,",.*$")
y 
 [1] ", Mar 1, 2019"  ", Mar 2, 2019"  ", Mar 3, 2019"  ", Mar 4, 2019" 
 [5] ", Mar 5, 2019"  ", Mar 6, 2019"  ", Mar 7, 2019"  ", Mar 8, 2019" 
 [9] ", Mar 9, 2019"  ", Mar 10, 2019" ", Mar 11, 2019" ", Mar 12, 2019"
 [13] ", Mar 13, 2019" ", Mar 14, 2019" ", Mar 15, 2019" ", Mar 16, 2019"
 [17] ", Mar 17, 2019" ", Mar 18, 2019" ", Mar 19, 2019" ", Mar 20, 2019"
 [21] ", Mar 21, 2019" ", Mar 22, 2019" ", Mar 23, 2019" ", Mar 24, 2019"
 [25] ", Mar 25, 2019" ", Mar 26, 2019" ", Mar 27, 2019" ", Mar 28, 2019"
 [29] ", Mar 29, 2019" ", Mar 30, 2019" ", Mar 31, 2019"
```

But now when I use `mdy` I get all the first 12 days wrong.

```
mdy(y)

[1] "2019-01-20" "2019-02-20" "2019-03-20" "2019-04-20" "2019-05-20" "2019-06-20"
[7] "2019-07-20" "2019-08-20" "2019-09-20" "2019-10-20" "2019-11-20" "2019-12-20"
[13] "2019-03-13" "2019-03-14" "2019-03-15" "2019-03-16" "2019-03-17" "2019-03-18"
[19] "2019-03-19" "2019-03-20" "2019-03-21" "2019-03-22" "2019-03-23" "2019-03-24"
[25] "2019-03-25" "2019-03-26" "2019-03-27" "2019-03-28" "2019-03-29" "2019-03-30"
[31] "2019-03-31"
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

#### SessionInfo

I added SessionInfo as requested

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) 
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=es_CL.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=es_CL.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=es_CL.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=es_CL.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] stringr_1.3.1   dplyr_0.7.6     rvest_0.3.2     xml2_1.2.0      XML_3.98-1.16  
[6] lubridate_1.7.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.18     rstudioapi_0.7   knitr_1.20       bindr_0.1.1     
 [5] magrittr_1.5     tidyselect_0.2.4 R6_2.2.2         rlang_0.2.2     
 [9] httr_1.3.1       tools_3.4.4      pacman_0.4.6     selectr_0.4-1    
 [13] htmltools_0.3.6  yaml_2.2.0       rprojroot_1.3-2  digest_0.6.17   
 [17] assertthat_0.2.0 tibble_1.4.2     crayon_1.3.4     bindrcpp_0.2.2    
 [21] purrr_0.2.5      curl_3.2         glue_1.3.0       evaluate_0.11    
 [25] rmarkdown_1.10   stringi_1.2.4    pillar_1.3.0     compiler_3.4.4  
 [29] backports_1.1.2  pkgconfig_2.0.2
```

Comment: `mdy(x)` works on my end.

Comment: Can you confirm what you get for the 10th date?

Comment: It worked for me as well, for all the dates. Can you update your question to include the output from `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Added the sessionInfo as requested, I am starting to think this has to do with the locale

Comment: @DerekCorcoran That might be it. With the same version of `lubridate` as you, I get the right result; the main difference seems to be that I have `LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: Yes @duckmayr, I checked una an ec2 instance with a different locale, and it seems that that was the problem

Comment: @DerekCorcoran I don't know for sure (I wasn't the down voter -- or any of the close voters), but I'd have to guess that since others couldn't reproduce the problem on their computer they thought your question didn't accurately present a reproducible problem. Just a little further inquiry, of course, reveals what the issue was.

Comment: Thank you @duckmayr, I will try to reset the locale and see if that fixes the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just as @duckmayr thought it was a locale promblem, as shown above in my sessioninfo my locale was set up as follows:

```
locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=es_CL.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=es_CL.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=es_CL.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=es_CL.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
```

When I changed the LC_TIME to en_US.UTF-8 everything was fixed, when I did it:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", 'en_US.UTF-8')
```

Then using `mdy` worked just fine. Hope this helps someone with a similar problem in the future